# Pinterest app search box

Tags: java, android

Please, i need to implement in Android an edit text search like Pinterest app. Basically, every single word typed into the edit text "acquire" a "x" icon and the user can delete a word clicking the x icon. I've searched some library but no success. Someone knows how can I do it please?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I implemented similar with TextWatcher class,

```
 searchBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    getFilter().filter("search:" + s.toString());
                }

  });
```

> manage clear button with FocusListener,

```
 searchBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                        if (!hasFocus) {  
                          closeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else { 
                          closeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the Pinterest app draws a close button in every single word. Unfortunately I can't post an image here because I don't have sufficient reputation, but you can check it on Pinterest app. Thanks